# Error: `class_eval': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I run a command `to generate a model`

> rails generate model Ip ip_address:string

I recieved folloing error in console

> `class_eval': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)

Description of error:

```
  /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:407:in `class_eval': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:91:in `register_klass_file'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:531:in `method_added'
from (eval):1:in `block in public_task'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:407:in `class_eval'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:407:in `block in public_task'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:406:in `each'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:406:in `public_task'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:162:in `<class:AppGenerator>'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:145:in `<module:Generators>'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:138:in `<module:Rails>'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rails-3.1.1/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rails:19:in `load'
from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

Can you please let me know what should I do to generate a model?

Comment: I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails version 3.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I found the cause:

The reason was I had opened the webrick server in a tab `rails server --debugger`

Means If webrick server is already running , we can't run any command like `scaffold`  `generate model` will not be working.

Thanks !